# Database versioning and migration techniques for schema & data

Tags: database, versioning, database-schema

I want to know what are the different techniques & tools used for database versioning and migration. I am also interested in saving a snapshot of the data along with the schema changes. Would that be a good practice?

I have come across tools like [`alembic`](http://alembic.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) and [`sqitch`](https://metacpan.org/module/App%3a%3aSqitch), although I haven't used either. I have around 200 table in PostgreSQL.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. Read about using [Liquibase with PostrgeSQL](http://www.liquibase.org/databases)
2. Ask you DBA to create data- (or full) dumps, which you store with ALTER-dumps of Liquibase